# View component hierarchy in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, developer-tools

When debugging a React website, I can view the component hierarchy using the [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en):

[image: picture of React devtools]

How can I do the same in React Native? The rage shake menu contains an 'inspector' but it only seems to let me inspect a single element by tapping it - I don't see any way to browse the full component hierarchy.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, since version 0.12 of react-native, the Devtools "React" Tab does not work anymore.
It's [a known issue](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/known-issues.html#devtools-react-tab-does-not-work).

There's a [quite active discussion on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/229) that has been open for a while, but no solutions yet.

**UPDATE**

The Devtools "React" tab still don't work in Chrome, but the latest [Nuclide](http://nuclide.io/) has it built in! (It's an IDE built on top of Atom).

With Atom installed with the Nuclide package, start your app and deactivate chrome or safari debugging.

Then, pressing `Cmd+Shift+P` in Atom will trigger the command palette and you can toggle the dev tools by searching for React Native Inspector:

[image: Inspector]

Comment: Yeah, there just doesn't seem to be a truly working debugger for React Native at the moment. +1, this is currently the only real correct answer, but I'm not it purely because I expect it to become obsolete in the next couple of months and don't want to have to come back to unaccept it when it does. :)

Comment: @MarkAmery fair enough :) I do hope it becomes obsolete soon enough :)

Comment: @MarkAmery FYI, the developer tools are still not working with Chrome but they are now in Nuclide :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using the standalone [react-devtools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/tree/master/packages/react-devtools) app with React Native 0.55.

1. Run `npm install -g react-devtools`
2. Run `react-devtools`
3. Open React Native app and select "Start Remote JS Debugging" from [dev menu](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging)